# Ocultar parametros en el QueryString

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta funcion que utilizo para enviar parametros por medio de QueryString:

```
<script>

    function Enviar(){

    var string_request;
    usuario = document.getElementById('Usuario').value;
    password = document.getElementById('Password').value;

    string_request = "Default.asp?Usuario=" + usuario + "&Password=" + password;                        
    window.open(string_request);

    }

</script>
```

El problema es que al ingresar a la pagina web Default.asp se visualiza la información del usuario y la contraseña
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe de alguna forma para ocultar esta infromación ?

Comment: No podes enviar los datos por post?

Comment: ¿Es necesario que envíes esta información sensible por QueryString? Creo que sería mejor usar variables de sesión.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los parámetros tendrías que pasarlos en el cuerpo de la petición, pero lamentablemente una petición GET no tiene cuerpo (`body`), así tendrás que usar POST.

El problema es que esto significa que tendrás que cambiar el código, porque al cargar una nueva página mediante una URL siempre se hace una petición con el método GET.

Simplemente crea un formulario (`form`) que apunte a `Default.asp` y que tenga como inputs el usuario ya la contraseña, no te haría falta ni usar Javascript:

```
<form action="Default.asp"  target="_blank" method="post">

    <label for="Usuario"><b>Usuario</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="Usuario" required>

    <label for="Password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="Password" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Al tener `target="_blank"`, al mandar el formulario se abrirá una nueva pestaña

Comment: Cabe decir que si no tiene un certificado SSL y un sitio bajo `https` no hay ninguna garantía de seguridad, use lo que use. En cambio, con `SSL+POST` los datos viajarán seguros.

Comment: Entendido, solo me queda una duda al mostrar el contenido de la pagina Defaul.asp como recibo el usuario y el password para guardarlos en variables ?

Comment: Esa parte ya depende un poco de qué tienes en backend, pero en general no hay apenas diferencia entre leer parámetros de la URL y del cuerpo al recibir una petición.

Answer (score 2):

El Método [GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) envía información en la query string. El Método [POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) envía información en el cuerpo de la petición HTTP.

Si bien aún en la petición POST es posible ver esa información usando el inspector de comunicaciones del navegador esta no es visible dentro de la querystring.

Si estas enviando información de un formulario puedes agregar el método a usar como un parámetro de la forma `<form id='miforma' method='POST'>`

Comment: hola, es tipo de respuesta no es aceptada por la comunidad, te recomiendo que leas 
[Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), esta respuesta podría ser eliminada, 
no te lo tomes a mal , son las reglas del sitio .Saludos.